# Modify a function without editing template

Tags: functions, filters, templates, hooks, actions

I'm wondering how I can modify a function without touching the template file.

The following function is called in my theme in the `template-functions.php` file:

```
    if( ! function_exists( 'book_landing_page_footer_credit' ) ) :
/**
 * Footer Credits 
 */
function book_landing_page_footer_credit(){

    echo '<div class="site-info">';
    esc_html_e( 'Copyright &copy;&nbsp;', 'book-landing-page' ); 
    echo esc_html( date_i18n( 'Y' ) );
    echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '&#46;&nbsp;</a>';
    printf('<a href="%1$s">Book Landing Page By %2$s</a>&#46;&nbsp;', esc_url( __( 'http://raratheme.com/wordpress-themes/book-landing-page/', 'book-landing-page' ) ), 'Rara Theme');
    printf( esc_html__( 'Powered by %s', 'book-landing-page' ), '<a href="'. esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'book-landing-page' ) ) .'" target="_blank">WordPress&#46;</a>' );
    echo '</div>';

}
endif;
```

Which is referenced in the `template-hooks.php` file like so:

```
add_action( 'book_landing_page_footer', 'book_landing_page_footer_credit', 40 );
```

My question is, how can I modify that function without touching the template files?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
if (!function_exists('new_credit')) {
    function new_credit() {
        echo 'This is my site';
    }
    add_filter('book_landing_page_footer_credit', 'new_credit');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oviously, you'll have to edit something if you want to modify it. So, your best course of action is to create a child theme, with its own function file.

A filter, as you tried, won't work, because there is no filter hook in the function that you are trying to modify. What you can do, is [remove the action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) that is printing the footer and then add a new action on the same hook. Like this:

```
add_action ('wp_head','wpse252108_remove_add_action');

function wpse252108_remove_add_action() {
  remove_action ('book_landing_page_footer', 'book_landing_page_footer_credit', 40);
  add_action ('book_landing_page_footer', 'new_credit', 40)
  }
```

Because it's unclear where in the flow `template-hooks.php`, the place where the original action is added, is loaded, it is possible that `wp_head` is too early to do the add/remove action. Perhaps `wp_footer` is better, though that in turn might be too late.

Comment: The template file template-hooks.php is actually called in the themes function.php file. I tried using wp_footer but that didn't work...wp_head worked just fine.